# 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl'

Tags: asp.net

I tried to get the LoginName control inside LoginView LoggedIn template , despite several methods, the code still could not work.

I wished to change the default username to the customer name. I tried finding the control inside the LoggedInTemplate but this error appear :

```
 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl' and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Here is the code:

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
   <LoggedInTemplate> 


                 Hello, <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server"></asp:LoginName>

                 <br /> 

                 <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: 5px "> 
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="~/Home.aspx" Font-Underline="True" />
                </div></div>
        </LoggedInTemplate>


    </asp:LoginView>
```

code at the back:

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LoginName loginName = LoginView1.LoggedInTemplate.FindControl("LoginName1") as LoginName;
       // LoginName loginName = LoginView1.FindControl("LoginName1") as LoginName;

       // loginName.FormatString = fullName;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine (it's your commented code):

```
LoginName loginName = LoginView1.FindControl("LoginName1") as LoginName;
loginName.FormatString = fullName;
```

I think your problem is that you never hit the Login1_LoggedIn method. Try adding a breakpoint in your method, start debugging and see if it hits.